# Character encoding issue in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

In my database, I have some content like this

`അവരുടെ മനസ്സുകളില്‍`.

But, when i am trying to fetch the content using `PHP` and display it in broswer, it is showing only some question marks like `????????? ???????. ??????`.

I tried to set the content type header like this

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

But it doesnt work.

How can i solve this ? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you got this broken during data fetch and you are setting display encoding - it's already too late. Simply ensure correct encoding during connection by using either using proper method like `mysqli_set_charset()` or do query `SET NAMES UTF8` just after your connect to DB

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the method you are using to connect to the DB, you should be specifying the charset.

With PDO, you can specify the charset in `PDO::__construct()`, such as: `charset=UTF-8`

Otherwise you have [`mysqli::set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) for MySQLi, or god forbid you're still using `mysql_*` functions there's [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)